# Issues with UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am using UINavigationController in my app. While going "Back" I want to skip one view. What I am currently doing is this :

In the viewDidAppear of the view I don't want to see I check to see if it appeared from a back button click, if so I call :

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But what happens is this:

the unwanted view and the previous view get morphed into one view (one on top of the other).

more explanation:

the unwanted view is the 2nd view and I want to go to the rootview:
Another code that I used was:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimation:YES]
```

The problem with this approach is 2:
   a) I still get a back button in the navigation bar that I should not be getting
   b) The toolbar items that should be there are not there. (the toolbar itself is there, though!)

Can anyone kindly let me know what I did wrong here ? Thanks.

Comment: from where is this message sent ?

Comment: @Vince : from the 2nd view  at  viewDidAppear function ...

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
int count = [self.navigationController.viewControllers count];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:count-2]]
```

Keep in mind the count is an array starting at 0 so just do count - x, taking that into consideration.

Also I am pretty sure this would work but it doesn't look clean:

```
UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;

[navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

What I needed to do in order to sovle this problem was this ::

Customize the backbutton function from the 3rd view and in the action handler popToRootViewController

Thanks.